# OpenFileDialog & SaveFileDialog Pop-up search with filter in C#

Tags: c#, filter, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I have openFileDialog and saveFileDialog with filter (only *.dvbcfg* extention):

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "DVB Configuration File (*.dvbcfg)|*.dvbcfg";
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "dvbcfg";
saveFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
```

It works properly, but when I'm trying to type filename manually it shows files with any extentions w/o filtering and opens/saves them (first - open file, second - save file):
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFZqm.png)

How to show **only** files that matches *saveFileDialog.Filter*?

*P.S. I have overwrite function in saveFileDialog.*

**UPD** I have another option - throw an exception when user selected wrong filetype, but I have no idea how to get only file extention from *saveFileDialog.FileName* string.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. You can always enter `*.*` in filename text field and press enter which will show you all the files in current directory, completely ignoring Filter dropdown.

Comment: The problem is that using wrong file may cause damage to expencive equipment (DVB-3030 Digital Modulator in this case) even if I'm using try/catch to get variables from files (they need to be integers, in try segment I have Convert.ToInteger32) and variable ranges in if/else checks (for example Frequency range should be 10MHz - 90 MHz with 100Hz step). Since programm will be used by students, they can purposelly try to break it.

Comment: @NaiLeD you can easily avoid that by validating the selected filenameand contents. That's something you'd have to do anyway, even if you trusted your users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a certain point, you have to "trust" your users. You can *steer* them towards good ways of working with your program, but at a certain point, you have to recognise that you've put enough *simple* barriers in their way to prevent accidental misuse<sup>1</sup> but you're unlikely to be able to create enough barriers (in these dialogs) to prevent malicious misuse.

> The problem is that using wrong file may cause damage to expensive equipment (DVB-3030 Digital Modulator in this case) even if I'm using try/catch to get variables from files (they need to be integers, in try segment I have `Convert.ToInteger32`) and variable ranges in if/else checks (for example Frequency range should be 10MHz - 90 MHz with 100Hz step). Since program will be used by students, they can purposely try to break it.

And nothing in your current question (or sought answer) would prevent someone from renaming any arbitrary file to have a `.dvbcfg` extension.

At this point, you "trust" that the user has given you the filename they wish to use. What you need to do next is to validate the *contents* of the file. If it has a `.dvbcfg` extension but isn't actually a valid DVB config file, you need to reject it. If it doesn't have a `.dvbcfg` extension (hey, maybe they're working with an old file system that only allows 8.3 file names :-)) but turns out to have valid content, why be churlish and *reject* that file?

I would recommend more than just wrapping `ToInteger32` calls in `try`/`catch`. Go through the file. Ensure it contains *exactly what it should and nothing else*. Read each parameter value and probably use `TryParse` on those. Because your code now "expects" to receive invalid inputs. Then validate ranges, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which I'd say you've already got.

Comment: Since .dvbcfg files will be created only by using this program, I've decided to add MD5 checksum of all values that will be saved to file. Also, by saying "invalid inputs" I've meant this: generally no invalid values can pass via checks I made (only valid ones for DVB-3030), but, for example, setting signal power to 50 dBm at the set frequency to 90 MHz may cause laws to be violated (just an example), so violating the laws will be on the user's conscience, but I want to protect them from using modified file that can lead them to violate the laws by accident.